# Read Pandas DataFrame object like a flatfile

Tags: python, pandas

I have an custom Python library function that takes a csv flat file as input that is read using `data = open('file.csv', 'r').read()`. But currently I've the `data` processed in Python as a Pandas DataFrame. How can I pass this DataFrame as a flat file object that my custom library function accepts?

As a work around I'm writing the DataFrame to disk and reading it back using the `read` function which is causing adding a second or two for each iteration. I want to avoid using this process.

Comment: you should consider posting your custom function that will enable the community to give better answers

Comment: Unfortunately it's an internal library which I cannot share with the community.

Comment: As an alternative, you should store the df as pickle object which will be easier to read .

Comment: If you want us to determine how to pass a flat file object that your custom library function accepts, then you need to share your custom library function.

Answer (score 0):

In the to_csv method of pandas DataFrame, if you don't provide any argument you get the CSV output returned as a string. So you can use the to_csv method on your DataFrame, that produces the same output as you are getting by storing and reading the DataFrame again.